# Why isn't my sprite moving with accelerometer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been trying to fix this for hours now, with no luck.  I'm trying to have my CCSprite subclass (thePlayer) move across the screen along the Y axis in relation to the tilt of the device.  I've done it before, and everything should work, but for some reason it isn't.  Here is the code:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    CGSize WinSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1
#define kRestAccelX -0.6
#define kShipMaxPointsPerSec (WinSize.height*0.5)        
#define kMaxDiffX 0.2
    UIAccelerationValue rollingX, rollingY, rollingZ;
    rollingX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    float accelX = acceleration.x - rollingX;
    float accelDiff = accelX - kRestAccelX;
    float accelFraction = accelDiff / kMaxDiffX;
    float pointsPerSec = kShipMaxPointsPerSec * accelFraction;
    _shipPointsPerSecY = pointsPerSec;
    //CCLOG(@"PointsPerSec: %f", _shipPointsPerSecY);
    CGPoint pos = thePlayer.position;
    pos.y += _shipPointsPerSecY;
    CCLOG(@"Pos.y: %f", pos.y);
    thePlayer.position = pos;
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize WinSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    float maxY = WinSize.height - thePlayer.contentSize.height / 2;
    float minY = thePlayer.contentSize.height/2;
    float derp = _shipPointsPerSecY;
    //CCLOG(@"Derp: %f", derp);
    float newY = thePlayer.position.y + (_shipPointsPerSecY * dt);
    //CCLOG(@"NewY: %f", newY);
    newY = MIN(MAX(newY, minY), maxY);
    thePlayer.position = ccp(thePlayer.position.x, newY);
    //CCLOG(@"Player position Y: %f", thePlayer.position.y);
}
```

This is probably the second most annoying problem I have ever had, so any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how and where did you wire `accelerometer:didAccelerate:` selector to the accelerometer?

Comment: Just in my GameWorld layer, which is the standard CCScene that one would make to create a new scene in cocos2d.  I'm receiving accelerometer data for sure, but it's... I don't really know whats happening actually...

Comment: maybe your filtering filters it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `pos.y` is ultimately being adjusted based on `acceleration.x`; just want to make sure you are not confusing your X and Y values.

Also note that X and Y from an accelerometer usually relate to the same alignment of the screen, regardless of its orientation. Thus in landscape, acceleration.x is actually your Y value, and vice-versa. In case that applies here as well.